# How can I get the offset where a Python regular expression search found a match?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the offset of the match found using re.search().

http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/regex.html

This site explains how to get offsets of match components relative to the start of the match, but doesn't say how to get the offset of the match itself in the "haystack" string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Hello, this is a string'
>>> m = re.search(',\s[a-z]',s)
>>> m.group()
', t'
>>> m.start()
5
```

More info can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/regex.html#performing-matches).

Comment: Does this behave differently if I am using a compiled regex rather than re.search?

Comment: Nevermind, my stupidity.  I thought I was misunderstanding how to use regex but it turns out my regex was matching something different than I was expecting.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Ok, glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like this:

```
import re

for m in re.compile("[a-z]").finditer('what1is2'):
    print m.start(), m.group()
```

Comment: I tried using match.start() but it defaults to group 0, which is the whole match, and the relative offset of the whole match to the whole match is 0.

Comment: Nevermind, my stupidity.  I thought I was misunderstanding how to use regex but it turns out my regex was matching something different than I was expecting.  Thanks for your answer.